# SetText in a new activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, textview, oncreate

i get a an intent with a string i a new activity, i would like to disply the string inside a `TextView`, i tried to declare my `TextView` inside the `onCreate` but it crash. how i can do for disply the variable `"requestbuff"`?

```
public class RequestDetail extends MainActivity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String requestbuff =  intent.getExtras().getString("Requête");
        TextView details = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detailreq);
        details.setText(requestbuff);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.detail_req);
    }
}
```

Comment: The instruction of calling super method is always must be the first in method body. Also try to move setContentView to beginning of the method. So you'll have next order in onCreate method: 1) super 2) setContentView 3) anything else

Comment: The point of this is that you cannot use findViewById before setContentView, becouse view is not created yet, and you have no access to it components (in this example to TextView)

Comment: Thanks a lot, so stupid ahha.

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine. Put setContentView at the beginning of the method so the view is created. After that you can use findViewById()

```
public class RequestDetail extends MainActivity 
{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.detail_req);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String requestbuff =  intent.getExtras().getString("Requête");
    TextView details = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detailreq);
    details.setText(requestbuff);
}
}
```